# Sync Git Up To Server

Tags: linux, git, version-control

My git client is behind my git server by a couple revisions and a `git push` doesn't seem to work because I did something quirky:

I had a git server on a machine whose harddrive crashed. Luckily, I had a backup although the backup was a couple of months old. I then made a new server and placed the backup git files up on the server.

In the time between the crash, I had made changes to files and committed them to the server. I have, for example, 1.4.8.30 locally, but only 1.4.8.26 on the server. When I try to `git push` the changes to the master branch on the server, it thinks everything is up-to-date, even though I can see the server is behind.

How can I get these files up to the server? I am scared I am going to lose revisions, or that these two are not correctly synced now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Git, you have the complete repository locally (in .git directory).

Therefore a "restore" procedure should be:

- Create a new bare Git repo (on the server)

> git init --bare new-one.git

- change origin (on the client)

  > git remote rm origin
  >
  > git remote add origin path-to-new-one.git
- Push your local data to repo

  > git push --all

Note: This is gets more complicated if there are more than one users with different local commits. Hopefully, you do not need that ;)